# Entity Framework 4 mapping fragment error when adding new entity scalar

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity Framework 4 model-first design. I create a first draft of my model in the designer and all was well. I compiled, generated database, etc.

Later on I tried to add a string scalar (Nullable = true) to one of my existing entities and I keep getting this type of error when I compile:

> Error 3004: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line 569: No
>   mapping specified for properties
>   MyEntity.MyValue in Set MyEntities. An
>   Entity with Key (PK) will not
>   round-trip when:   Entity is type
>   [MyEntities.MyEntity]

I keep having to manually open the EDMX file and correct the XML whenever I add scalars.

Ideas on what's going on?

Comment: What, exactly, are you correcting?

Comment: I was manually editing the entity type and set mappings.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Have since discovered that after I add/change/delete properties on my entities I must "Generate Database from Model" before I compile otherwise I get 3004 mapping errors.

Comment: This is ridiculous! I'm creating my model FROM the database, not the other way around. I'm beginning to find EF quite buggy... :(

Comment: I've noticed that when I delete properties the updated version of the model still contains the old fields. I have to manually delete the fields. Adding this bit of info in case it helps anyone.

Comment: I am getting this error, and it seems exactly as if the database isn't in sync with the model. However I am using Code First, and cannot "Generate Database From Model". I have it set up to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, which for some reason isn't working with this additional property :/

Comment: if you are starting with a database and don't want to use VS to generate the database from code, rather than "Generate", try "Update model from database..."

Comment: Yeah, why am I bothering with EF, never had these kind of problems with linq2sql

Comment: UGH! I wasted hours on this one.  I describe this as the chicken and the egg error.  I would have done this step if I had not seen that error (As I had done multiple times before).  Please learn from this and go Code First, I never have issues like this Model First is so touchy.

Answer (score 43):

I just removed the offending tables from the model and then added them back and all was well.

Comment: Worked for me, too. Database first.

Comment: This still occurs in EF5, and this was the solution that worked for me. In my case, I had removed a column as well as added a Foreign Key relationship to the table (in case it helps anyone figure out why). Database first as well.

Comment: This seems like the best solution, and easy to remember. I will just remove then add from now on if I change the database.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well. Deleted the tables from the edmx file, updated the model from database twice (once for delete and another for refresh/add) and it worked. Happened to me while I already generated models from an existing database using db first and then later added foreign key constraints to my junction tables (many-to-many relationship). Once I removed the junction tables from edmx file everything was back to normal

Comment: When I got this error, I also noticed `public <datatype> MyColumnName1 { get; set; }` (note the **1**) appeared in the generated model.

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer especially with database first users

Answer (score 31):

For those of you who are creating a model from a database, I had this issue after I made changes to my DB. It happened when I changed a field name in the DB for one reason or another (I think it also happens if you change a data type).

The solution, for me, was to right-click on the workspace and choose "Update Model from Database". This should add the properties from the DB to your model, however, it does NOT remove your old properties and those will give you the 3004 error.

Right-click on the workspace and choose "Validate". This should give you an error list showing the offending properties. You can then right-click each offending property and delete it manually from your model.

This fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: **This should give you an error list showing the offending properties. You can then right-click each offending property and delete it manually from your model.** this.

Comment: "Right-click on the workspace and choose 'Validate'" Hmm, I right clicked on the diagram VS generates from the edmx file and chose "Validate". I didn't see any errors. Was I validating the wrong thing?

Comment: solved my problem, mine occured because i was trying to do some code first. WHile previously i was using db forst. Than when failed i added tables in db and updated models and the probelm arise. there were 2 fields i removed and it worked (Y)

Comment: Hilarious this problem still exists. The "Validate" tip worked for me - had to manually delete a column from my model since updating from database didn't.

Comment: I think updating from the database never deletes stuff, it just adds to your model.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to modify your database without regenerating the entire model or recreating your database from the model, I find it's easiest and safest to amend the properties in the EDMX diagram via Visual Studio and then manually adjust the mappings which visual studio doesn't give access to.

The error will give you a line number:

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at line **569**

Just open the edmx file in a text editor, go to that line and it should be quite obvious what needs fixing. There's a section which will look like this:

```
<EntityTypeMapping TypeName="YourModel.YourType">
  <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="YourType">
    <ScalarProperty Name="PropertyName1" ColumnName="DatabaseColumn1" />
    <ScalarProperty Name="PropertyName2" ColumnName="DatabaseColumn2" />
    ...
  </MappingFragment>
</EntityTypeMapping>
```

Just make sure there's a node for each property/column name you need, and that all properties are also listed in the `<EntityType Name="YourTable">` section at the top of the edmx document

Comment: This was a good call - though it can be dangerous if you mess something up :)

Comment: This does solve the problem, although I am astounded that adding a column to the graphical view of the edmx does not do this! I wish that I could give you more points...

Answer (score 1):

If all your queries are written in stored procedures and you are just trying to fill the model then you could switch to a complex type which worked for me.

How to create a complex type:

1. Manually change the name of the
   Entity Generated class you are
   having issues with to a name not
   already in use in your edmx file.
2. Select the Model Browser window and
   right-click/add a new complex type.
3. Copy/Paste the properties of the
   original model to the complex type.
4. Map your stored procedures to the
   complex type.

   I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to do so without removing table from diagram and re-adding it, is by using Table Mapping option.

1. Goto to the model browser
2. Right click on table name.
3. Choose tablle mapping
4. Visual Studio will show a window with EF properties matching/missing table columns.
5. Select/match appropriate column to missing property

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I received the same problem after renaming a property on one of my entities.

I found out that the mapping between the property of my entity and the corresponding column in the table was not set.

You can set this using the editor by right clicking on the entity in the model and choosing "Table mapping". Make sure the properties are mapped to a column in the database.

Edit: I also needed to re-run my tt file to generate the new classes. (Might have been since I have it in another project?)

Answer (score 0):

After review the xml file (edmx), move the model to another project and realize that all is ok, I decided to close and open the Visual Studio and complile againt, then error disapears.